# slam map inconsistent

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, hector-slam, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I was building a map using hector slam, the result was good but I found map inconsistent when the robot U - turn from a dead end. I don't have odometry on the robot. The first picture shows the robot is going in to a dead end. The second picture shows the robot go back to the corridor that it has scanned before. There is some inconsistency on the mapping which it seems like the robot don't 'remember' the corridor and mapping a new area. May I know how could I solve this problem? Or do I just avoid dead end at any cost? Thank you.

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

This is the parameter for the hector mapping

```
<node pkg="hector_mapping" type="hector_mapping" name="hector_mapping"    output="screen">

<param name="use_tf_scan_transformation" value="true" />
>param name="use_tf_pose_start_estimate" value="false" />
<param name="scan_topic" value="scan" />

<param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="true"/>
<param name="map_frame" value="map" />
<param name="base_frame" value="base_link" />
<param name="odom_frame" value="base_link" />

<!-- Map size / start point -->
<param name="map_resolution" value="0.075"/>
<param name="map_size" value="512"/>
<param name="map_start_x" value="0.5"/>
<param name="map_start_y" value="0.5" />
<param name="laser_z_min_value" value="-2.5" />
<param name="laser_z_max_value" value="3.5" />

<!-- Map update parameters -->
<param name="update_factor_free" value="0.4"/>
<param name="update_factor_occupied" value="0.9" />    
<param name="map_update_distance_thresh" value="0.2"/>
<param name="map_update_angle_thresh" value="0.4" />
<param name="scan_subscriber_queue_size" value="25" />
<param name="map_multi_res_levels" value ="2"/>
</node>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134906/slam-map-inconsistent/) by [zero1985](https://answers.ros.org/users/6926/zero1985/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2014-03-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try with this parameters:

```
 <launch>
 <node pkg="hector_mapping" type="hector_mapping" name="hector_mapping"    output="screen">
 
 <!-- Frame names -->
 <param name="base_frame" value="base_link" />
 <param name="odom_frame" value="base_link" />
 <param name="output_timing" value="false"/>
 
 <param name="map_frame" value="map" />
 
 <!-- Tf use -->
 <param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="true"/>
 
 <!-- Map size / start point -->
 <param name="map_resolution" value="0.025"/>
 <param name="map_size" value="6000"/>
 <param name="map_start_x" value="0.5"/>
 <param name="map_start_y" value="0.5" />
 <param name="map_pub_period" value="1"/>
 <param name="laser_max_dist" value="20" />
 <param name="laser_z_min_value" value="-2.5" />
 <param name="laser_z_max_value" value="7.5" />
 <param name="update_factor_free" value="0.4"/>
 <param name="update_factor_occupied" value="0.7" />    
 <param name="map_update_distance_thresh" value="0.2"/>
 <param name="map_update_angle_thresh" value="0.06" />

 </node>
 </launch>
```

But the map also depend to the soft moves and the power of your CPU.

---

Originally posted by [alex.filgueira](https://answers.ros.org/users/11401/alex.filgueira/) with karma: 62 on 2014-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0